# didSelectRowAtIndexPath is in conflict with Tap Gesture Recognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I've set a Tap Gesture Recognizer in my ViewController via the Storyboard
(so all the tap in the view, will hide the keyboard if this one is showed)

The thing is that now, I have add a TableView in this View, and when I clic on a cell, the methode set with the Tap Gesture Recognizer is call, not `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

The "funny" thing, is that if I stay on the cell for 2seconds or more, the delegate `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called, not the `TapGestureRecognizer` methode.

Could you guys explain what happen here ? where and why am I wrong ?

Comment: when keyboard will open then add tap gesture and when keyboard will hide then remove tap gesture from the view, this is one way to do

Comment: @Jaimish : I've done that, it work perfectly for the TapGestureRecognizer method, but now, on my TableView, nothing is called when I single tap on a cell, and didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called when I stay press on the cell for 2secondes or more, I still wonder why.

Comment: You have tried the @Jan Greve answer?

Comment: Provide some code of Textfield or Textview delegate and also didselect method of tableview

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your `UITapGestureRecognizer` probably [cancels the touch event](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009279-CH1-SW34) when successfully recognizing a touch.

Try setting

```
tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

For a more thorough read on this topic, [have a look an the conceptual docs on gesture recognition](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html).

Comment: after Updating my code tahnks to Jaimish, I'm sure I have no gestures set on my view anymore, but the didSelectRowAtIndexPath is still called only when I stay press on the cell for more than 2secondes, nothing is call when I single tap on it (however, the cell still "blink" as it should when single tapped, is it possible that the code call another delegate, other tahn didSelectRowAtIndexPath ?)

Comment: Is your gesture recognizer's action called? How are you 'sure'? Have you imlemented `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath?` on your delegate? That could prohibit it as well.

Comment: Yep, I found out that in the storyboard, some gestureRecognizer were set to non-existants methods, after deleted them, it work perfectly !!

Thanks by the way :)

Comment: I recon that makes my answer correct and helpful then. Feel free to accept it.

Comment: @SmokeDispenser It is still not working for me , i am not table to select the items from my table view, i have implemented the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` method

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal this is not a forum. If you have a question yourself, feel free to ask it complying to [ask] after searching for it here. Explain in your question what you have tried and what didn't work.

Comment: Thank you very much man! Now i can use both didselectrowatindexpath and tapgesture with a single tap !

Answer (score -3):

Better way is don't use didSelectRowAtIndexpath method.

if you have to implement gestures on table view cell then create tap gesture in cellForRowAtIndexpath and using tag identify particular cell click.

Comment: @EdwardAnthony Can you please explain what is wrong here so I can learn things.