# Swift recognize tableView cell tap area

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

How can I detect a particular area tapped of a tableView cell porgrmatically?

For example, if the user taps the left half of the tableView Cell, didSelectRowAt is called and recognizes the left half of the cell.

**Pseudo:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    print("Entire cell tapped")

    if(left side of cell pressed){
      //cell.width /2
      print("left side half of cell pressed")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944670/didselectrowatindexpath-is-in-conflict-with-tap-gesture-recognizer) thread, adding a Gesture recognizer can conflict with the TableView interactions.

Hence, To achieve what you require, you will have to add a gesture recognizer to the `contentView` of the `UITableViewCell` and get the tapped location of the gesture. For this,

1. First, Define the `UITapGestureRecognizer` and the action within the `UITableViewCell` class. Refer the following code

```
    lazy var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapScreen))
.
.
.
    // Gesture action
    @objc func didTapScreen(touch: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let xLoc = touch.location(in: self.contentView).x // Getting the location of tap
        if xLoc > contentView.bounds.width/2 {
            // RIGHT
        } else {
            // LEFT
        }
    }
```

2. Add the following to the `init()` method of the custom cell as follows

```
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        contentView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        // Other setups
    }
```

I tried the code in a `UICollectionViewCell` and got the following output

[image]